# At least a constant fraction of the numbers has linear size.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be integers with $1\leq a_1\leq a_2 \leq ... \leq a_n \leq n$ and we know there exists a constant $c\geq 2$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \geq \frac{n^2}{c}$  (for example $c=100$).

I think the following statement should be true but how can I prove it?

There exist constants $c_1,c_2\geq 1$ such that $\frac{n}{c_1}$ of the numbers $a_i$, have a value of at least $\frac{n}{c_2}$.

Thoughts on this:

- If we had, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \geq n^2$ then clearly this can only hold when $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$, so this is kind of an extreme case.
- If for any set of $\frac{n}{c_1}$ numbers, the numbers in this set each had a value of (for example) $\frac{n}{\log{n}}$, then the total sum would be at most $\frac{n^2}{\log{n}}$.

Comment: It is easily provable, take $c_2=n$, then you can take any $c_1\leq n$, and the statement will read *at least $\frac{n}{c_1}$ of the numbers $a_i$ satisfy $a_i\geq 1$*.

The real question is, what do you wish to maximize/minimize? More of your setup would also help, i.e. do you pick $c$ first and wish to make a statement about all $n$, or something else? 

Also, please show your own attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim $c_1,c_2$ have to be constants, so their size does not depend on $n$. So you can't take $c_2=n$ right?

Comment: I guess then your statement is, for all $c\geq 2$, find $c_1,c_2\geq 1$ such that for any $n$, any integer sequence bounded by $n$ satisfying $\sum a_i\geq \frac{n^2}{c}$ also have at least $\frac{n}{c_1}$ elements larger than $\frac{n}{c_2}$.

Is this correct? Also, could you include your own attempt?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim this is correct. I will try to include what I thought of, even though I don't think it is any useful

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution, just a bound. Let $c,c_1,c_2$ be as above. Pick $n$ such that all the constants divide it (for convenience), and consider the sequence $\lbrace n,n,\dots,n,\frac{n}{c_2}-1,\frac{n}{c_2}-1,\dots,\frac{n}{c_2}-1\rbrace$, with $\frac{n}{c_1}-1$ terms of $n$. By choice of sequence, we see that the bounds are *not* satisfied, and thus it follows that $\sum a_i<\frac{n^2}{c}$. But we can calculate the sum as
$$n\cdot (\frac{n}{c_2}-1)+(\frac{n}{c_2}-1)\cdot (n-(\frac{n}{c_2}-1)) = n^2(\frac{1}{c_1}+\frac{1}{c_2}-\frac{1}{c_1c_2})-n(2-\frac{1}{c_1}-\frac{1}{c_2})-1.$$

since this polynomial in $n$ is bounded by $\frac{n^2}{c}$, and we can let $n$ get arbitrarily large, the square terms dominate and so we see

$$\frac{1}{c_1}+\frac{1}{c_2}-\frac{1}{c_1c_2}<\frac1c.$$

This bound in particular implies that $c_1\geq c$ and $c_2\geq c$, but is even stronger than those combined. I imagine you could prove some type of bounds in the other direction, but it has so far eluded me.